# xampp is not working after updating the DB

Tags: php, drupal-7, xampp

I updated the database, after that i pointed my drupal site to perticular db. I tried to login to my site, then i got this prompt error message.
I am using xampp.
[Screenshot : Error prompted while logging into Drupal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFwhD.png)

Any help will be appreciated.